# How to install GNU gettext on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, gnu, gettext

I need to install version 0.15 or higher of GNU's gettext.
I've downloaded :

> http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/gettext/gettext-0.18.3.1.tar.gz

from https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/

However I have no idea how to install it and there's no installation guide on their website.
How can I install it ?

Comment: Without a tool like Cygwin you won't be able to even run this program let alone install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's supposed to run on Windows. It's for Linux. Try `Cygwin`. I think it should have that package. At least it's listed [here](http://cygwin.com/packages/).

Answer (score 0):

To run linux tools in windows , you will have to install programs like [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/),[MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/),[GnuWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) that offer a Linux-like environment on Windows.

Cygwin is a Windows command line on steroids which runs tons of well-known, age-old, useful Unix commands , which is my personal favorite.A good introduction on Cygwin can be found [here](http://lifehacker.com/179514/geek-to-live--introduction-to-cygwin-part-i).

Many common Linux programs have already been ported to Windows and compiled versions have been made available online.For eg: you’ll find versions of Emacs for Windows [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/).

Some other alternatives to install Linux software on Windows can be found [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/170870/5-ways-to-run-linux-software-on-windows/).

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find my unofficial windows setup files: https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html

Comment: Could you please explain how to use those to accomplish the task? You can [edit] your post anytime.